# Malware and problems loading Tor

Tags: malware

Recently I tried going on Tor browser and couldn't get on. Got a malware warning.Still having trouble going on Tor. Even looks different. Takes up whole computer screen. I recently did have to go to a new anti virus. Tried deleting then reloading tor browser, (losing ALL my bookmarks). Still having issues.Any help would be appreciated.